# Checking for items in sublists

Tags: python, tree, iteration

Today I'll demonstrate a simple function that searches for a item in all sublists of a list. For this it uses iteration, and keep in mind that it can be slow because of this. How can I improve it? Linked lists?

I doubt `__contain__` can do the same.

```
def ListContainWSublist(searchfor, *args):

    Result = False

    for x in args:
        if type(x) == list:
            Result = ListContainWSublist(searchfor, *x)

        if x == searchfor:
            Result = True

    return Result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Proper type checking

To start off, you shouldn't be type checking like this:

> ```
> if type(x) == list:
>     ...
> ```

The proper way to go is to use Python's `isinstance(a, b)` function, where `a` is a value, and `b` is the type you're checking against. The portion of your code that involves type checking would be re-written like this:

```
if isinstance(x, list):
    ...
```

The difference here is that `isinstance` allows for inheritance when checking the type of a value, rather than simply checking the type of the value itself, which can be rather useful. If you're interested, you can read more about this at [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python).

---

## Nitpicks

You should have the user pass a list of values, not pass a variable amount of arguments. Your function signature should look like this:

```
def list_contain_sublist(search_for, collection):
    ...
```

Your names are rather nasty, especially for Python. In Python, variable and function names should be in `snake_case`, and classes should be in `PascalCase`. Not the other way around.

There's also no need for the `Result` variable. You can change this line:

> ```
> Result = ListContainWSublist(searchfor, *x)
> ```

To this:

```
return ListContainWSublist(searchfor, *x)
```

This line:

> ```
> Result = True
> ```

Should become:

```
return True
```

And then this line:

```
Result = False
```

Can be removed all-together.

---

Other than those things, it looks fine. There may be a way to do this without recursion, but I'm not sure how to. I'll leave that up to you to figure out.